# Procedure Syntax isn't correct

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm not new to PL/SQL or Procedure programming in an MSSQL database (2012). But I am rusty and I'm messing up the syntax.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddActivity]
    @activity_name nvarchar(255),
    @responsible_first_name nvarchar(255),
    @responsible_last_name nvarchar(255),
    @estimated_savings numeric(18),
    @estimated_start datetime,
    @estimated_end datetime,
    @department_id int,
    @description nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @return_code AS int = 0;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Department WHERE @department_id = id)
        BEGIN
            @return_code = -1
        END
    ELSE
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Activity WHERE @activity_name = activity_name)
            BEGIN
            /* There is no duplicate (supposedly) so insert the entry here. */
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                @return_code = -2
            END
RETURN @return_code
```

Help out a fellow developer and his rusty memory? :D

Comment: The procedural language in Microsoft SQL Server is called T-SQL, not PL/SQL (that's Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah see I'm messing up even that :'). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You can't have an empty BEGIN/END block in TSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `SET` the value in your variable(`@return_code`) which you have `DECLARE`. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddActivity]
    @activity_name nvarchar(255),
    @responsible_first_name nvarchar(255),
    @responsible_last_name nvarchar(255),
    @estimated_savings numeric(18),
    @estimated_start datetime,
    @estimated_end datetime,
    @department_id int,
    @description nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @return_code AS int = 0;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Department WHERE @department_id = id)
        BEGIN
            SET @return_code = -1
        END
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Activity WHERE @activity_name = activity_name)
            BEGIN
                SET @return_code = -2   --Removed the empty BEGIN/END by changing the IF NOT EXISTS to IF EXISTS
            END


RETURN @return_code
```

Comment: Hmm, it keeps telling me that "id" and "activity_name" are unresolved even though they are in the dbo.Activity and dbo.Department table.

Comment: SQL71501: Procedure: [dbo].[AddActivity] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Department].[id]

Comment: @Vipar:- Check if you have a space in your column names!

Comment: Just checked. I don't have any spaces.

Comment: @Vipar:- You are executing the procedure on Visual Studio?

Comment: yeah I haven't executed it yet, but yes.

Comment: @Vipar:- See the fix [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565459/FixingplusSSDTplusunresolvedplusreferenceplustoplu) . On SSMS it will work fine. You can check it but for Visual Studio you can go through the link which I have sent. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

At least one problem is`@return_code = -1`.  You need either `SET` or `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @return_code = -1
```

Comment: Oh, SET did the trick there. But I still get a syntax error after my first ELSE at the END part.